# Multiple media queries but only first one gets executed

Tags: css, responsive

I have three media queries in my scss but only the first one gets executed:
(They are in the botom of scss page). I have tried reversing the order but then I don't get styles even at my inspector.. Now I get them but they are not applied (look at the screenshoot below).

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .profile-banner {
    transform: translateY(0rem) !important;
    .img-div {
      margin-right: 1rem !important;
    }
    .profile-info {
      padding-top: 3rem;
      p {
        font-size: 12px !important;
      }
      h1 {
        font-size: 2.5rem !important;
      }
    }
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .profile-info {
    padding-top: 2rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .profile-info {
    padding-top: 1rem;
  }
}
```

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check if in your html page you put correctly the meta tag.

```
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the information you have provided, it looks like all three media rules are being applied correctly here.

If all three are being called then your viewport must be less than 450px, as that then meets all three queries.

If the view port was 451px then you would only see the two sets of styles and queries in the console, as last one doesn't meet query.

The reason that the max 700 queries style are being applied is a separate issue.

This comes down to the "degree of specificity" that is applied in the CSS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Note in the console, that the applied style has two classes included in the selector, so that is considered more relevant than the ones in the other queries.

E.g:

> .profile-banner .profile-info

Is more specific then:

> .profile-info